# Cofinality for natural transformations

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

Given a diagram $D\colon\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow\mathcal{D}$, we say that a functor $J\colon\mathcal{I}\longrightarrow{C}$ is [**cofinal**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor) if we have a natural isomorphism
$$
\mathrm{colim}\left(\mathcal{C}\overset{D}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{D}\right)\cong\mathrm{colim}\left(\mathcal{I}\overset{J}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{C}\overset{D}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{C}\right).
$$
With a number of ways to check cofinality for functors (e.g. [1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05US), [2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04E6)), this notion ends up being very useful in practice as a computational tool.

What about cofinality for natural transformations? Namely, given functors $D,D'\colon\mathcal{C}\rightrightarrows\mathcal{D}$, call a natural transformation $\eta\colon D\Rightarrow D'$ **final** if postcomposition with it induces a bijection¹
$$
\mathsf{Nat}\left(\Delta_{(-)},D\right)\overset{\eta}{\underset{\cong}{\dashrightarrow}}\mathsf{Nat}\left(\Delta_{(-)},D'\right),
$$
and hence a natural isomorphism $\lim(D)\cong\lim(D')$. Do we have, as in the case of cofinality for functors, easy(-ish) to check conditions implying that a natural transformations is final?

[Motivation: If so, this would similarly be useful for either computations, or for expressing co/limits of somewhat contrived functors as co/limits of nicer, more naturally-appearing, ones. For example, having such a notion in hand, one would be able to e.g. compute the $\pi_0$ of a complicated simplicial set $S_\bullet$ by first finding a “final simplicial map” $S_\bullet\to T_\bullet$ to a simpler simplicial set $T_\bullet$ and then computing the $\pi_0$ of $T_\bullet$.]

---

¹Here's a picture of the induced cones of $D'$ over some object $X$ of $\mathcal{D}$:

[image]

Comment: This is a right orthogonality condition. As such it is closed under composition and retracts and limits and has the 2-out-of-6 property. If $\mathcal{D}$ is, say, accessible then you only need to check the condition against a small set of objects. I don’t think there’s much more that can be said in this generality, since it depends on $\mathcal{D}$, unlike cofinality of functors.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks! If we impose nice conditions on $\mathcal{D}$ (say being a topos or the category of models of a finite limits theory, etc.), then would “cofinal natural transformations” admit useful characterisations?

Comment: I doubt it. If anything it may be more important to look at the diagram shape $\mathcal{C}$. For instance, if $\mathcal{C}$ has a cofinal full subcategory then you know that the components of the diagram outside that subcategory don't matter.

Comment: Robert Paré's [Morphisms of colimits](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-013-9357-0) might be relevant?

Comment: @RoaldKoudenburg Hmm... I think the paper answers a different question, which is related to this one. Namely, referring to the very first diagram in p. 2 there, I think  my question would correspond to taking $F=\mathrm{id}$ and studying when the induced morphism between co/limits is an iso. From what I understand, however, Paré is studying what would be necessary to have a morphism, not necessarily an iso, between the co/limits. In any case, the paper looks very interesting! Thanks for the pointer :)